# Blazor CascadingValue

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side

My goal is to get some data passed to common layout code. Code snippets of what I have but the value of **linkedCyclones** is not cascading to the lower component **NavLinkedCyclones**.

Not sure who to pass data into a layout component. I thought the cascade would do the trick but I'm either doing it wrong or it doesn't work the same way with layouts.

The **LinkedSetIds** is always *null* in the **NavLinkedCyclones.razor**

I welcome any suggestions.

NavCycloneMenu.razor

```
        <CascadingValue Value="@linkedCyclones" Name="LinkedSets">
            <AuthorizeView Roles="Admin, Tier2, Tier3">
                <Authorized>
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="CycloneCalculator/GasMix">
                            <span class="oi oi-beaker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Gas Mix
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </Authorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="CycloneCalculator/CycloneSizing">
                            <span class="oi oi-calculator" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cyclone Sizing
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </Authorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </CascadingValue>

@code {
    private int[] linkedCyclones { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        linkedCyclones = new int[] { 101, 202, 303 };
    }
}
```

GasMix.razor

```
@layout CycloneLayout;

<div>
    <h1>Gas Mix</h1>
</div>
```

CycloneLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <NavCycloneMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
        <LoginDisplay />
        <a class="top-row-text" href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        <NavLinkedCyclones />
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

NavLinkedCyclones.razor

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Linked Cyclones</legend>

    @for (int i = 0; i < LinkedSetIds.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        <a href=""><img class="img-linked-cyclone" src="images/CycloneLogoNoWhite.png" alt="Cyclone"> Cyclone @(i+1)</a>
        <div class="oi oi-arrow-thick-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div class="oi oi-arrow-thick-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div class="oi oi-arrow-thick-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    }

    <a href=""><img class="img-linked-cyclone" src="images/CycloneLogoNoWhite.png" alt="Cyclone"> Cyclone @LinkedSetIds.Length</a>
</fieldset>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "LinkedSets")]
    public int[] LinkedSetIds { get; set; }
}
```